# getting logged in user info (wp-load.php) from parent directory

Tags: php, functions, login, wp-load.php

Directory structure:

- https://www.example.com/test.php
- https://www.example.com/blog/wp-load.php

test.php:

```
require_once("blog/wp-load.php");
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
print_r($current_user);
```

The result is an empty array

```
WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( ) [ID] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [filter] => [site_id:WP_User:private] => 0 )
```

If I put test.php inside /blog/ directory, it will work. I checked similar questions and it looks like a cookie problem, but I already tested all solutions for cookie problems and it didn't help

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com/blog');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.example.com');
```